# Finding best route using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, network-analyst, route, network-dataset

I have 4 shapefiles which are 2 locations, roads, and bridges.
I am trying to find the best way from A to B with fewer bridges.

I tried network analysis but I don't have a Network data source, should I create one or there is a different way to solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could create one or you can use some credits and have access to Esri's network.

It looks like you already have the road layer so you should probably create the network yourself.

I think it is 0.5 credits per route if you decide to use their network. The number of credits used depends on what you are doing. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/network-analyst/an-overview-of-the-network-analyst-toolbox.htm